# How do you split part of an excel cell into another cell?

Tags: vba, excel

There's a list of cells that looks like `[a-z ]* [1-9.]*`. I want to split the numric part into the adjacent cell. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you want VBA or will a formula do?

Comment: Is there guaranteed a space between alpha and numeric part as you have shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For another formula approach, you could try this to extract the numeric part of A1:

`=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),255)`

Comment: +1 efficiently done. You might want to add a second formula to substitute this out of the original string to leave the leading text only.

Answer (score 1):

here's a vba snippet, in case this helps:

```
Dim s As String: s = "wergyuklwgh9235783850298"
Dim i As Long:
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    If Mid(s, i, 1) Like "#" Then Exit For
Next
sLeft = Left(s, i - 1)  ' now sLeft contains "wergyuklwgh"
sRght = Mid(s, i)       ' now sRght contains "9235783850298"
```

could put this into a public function to make a little UDF, useable from the formula bar